# Inserting an integer variable as an argument in a Qstring and sending it to Serial.write

Tags: c++, qt

I am building a control software in Qt 5.3.0 for a 3D printer. I want to send commands to a translational stage through the serial port. I am facing the problem call of overloaded arg(QByteArray) is ambiguous.

It is giving me an error saying `call of overloaded 'arg(QByteArray)' is ambiguous`

I have tried looking up documentation for appending an integer to a QString, I think it is an error in typecasting.

```
bool DLP3Dprinter::StepMotorMotion(unsigned char Type, unsigned char SpeedValue[2], unsigned int TravelValue){

const double stepSize = 0.047625;
int Microsteps = (int)(TravelValue/stepSize); //to convert from micrometers to microsteps
int Speed = (int)(SpeedValue*(1.6384/stepSize)); //to convert um/s to Zaber units /s

switch(Type){
        case ManualUp:
        Serial.write(QString("/1 set maxspeed %1").arg(QByteArray::number(Speed));  //Speed does not need to be set every time, only if it changes
        Serial.readAll();
        Serial.write(QString("/1 move rel %1").arg(QByteArray::number(Microsteps));
        Serial.readAll();
        break;
```

Comment: use `Serial.write(QString("/1 set maxspeed %1").arg(QString(QByteArray::number(Speed)));` and
    `Serial.write(QString("/1 move rel %1").arg(QString(QByteArray::number(Microsteps)));`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling `.arg(QByteArray::number(x))`, you can directly pass the number as `.arg(x)`.

```
QString str("I am %1 years old.");
int age = 100;
QString str1 = str.arg(QString::number(age));
QString str2 = str.arg(age);

Q_ASSERT(str1 == str2);
```

QString provides [comprehensive overloads](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#public-functions) for integer arguments allows us to conveniently pass in variables with different types.

---

> I think it is an error in typecasting.

That's about right, I think.

To shed some light on the error of the ambiguous overload, it seems like `QByteArray` has a private `operator int`. (That's what I observe from the completer. Qt don't seem to document this type-cast, maybe since it's private.) This implies that QByteArray can be *implicitly* converted to an `int`. This will hit a bunch of overloads, marking the command as ambiguous. Here are some of the overloads that were hit (copied from `qstring.h`, not sure if this has changed since Qt 5.3).

```
QString arg(const QString &a, int fieldWidth = 0, QChar fillChar = QLatin1Char(' ')) const;
QString QString::arg(int a, int fieldWidth, int base, QChar fillChar);
QString QString::arg(uint a, int fieldWidth, int base, QChar fillChar);
QString QString::arg(long a, int fieldWidth, int base, QChar fillChar);
QString QString::arg(ulong a, int fieldWidth, int base, QChar fillChar);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do

```
Serial.write(QString("/1 set maxspeed %1").arg(QString::number((Speed)));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add to or more number you should use:

```
QString str("I am %1 or %2 years old.");
qDebug()<<str.arg(33).arg(44); //and .arg for every next argument
```